# why click event not show alert in angular js library?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I make a simple demo in which I make custom cell of table like that

```
 {
            field: 'id',
            name: '',
            enableColumnMenu: false,
            cellTemplate: 'edit-button.html',
            width: 34,
            enableFiltering: false,
        },
```

I am using angular ui grid from here 
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro

I try to get click event but it not working properly .I try like that

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="self.editRow(grid, row)">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

I make **editRow** function in controller .but it not fire why

```
      self.editRow = editRow;

  function editRow(grid, row) {
   alert('--')
  }
```

I have one more Question why  it show error when I include dependency of **$uibModal** already include angular and ui bootsrap files

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/G6AyH2TPfqOxnyPKx0g1?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uiGrid binds the parent scope to a scope called "appScope", you can get your functions from there (docs here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope)

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="grid.appScope.c.editRow(grid, row)">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/jSD6G7K3eHiKNignNnoR?p=preview

$uibModal couldn't be found because you're probably still using an older version of ui-bootstrap that still uses the non-prefixed version of the services ($modal)

Comment: please provide plunker

Comment: @user944513 I've updated my code, I forgot to add 'c' because you're using controllerAs

Comment: i want to open a model on click of button